# RUN Cocos2d-x Projects in linux

Tags: cocos2d-x, android-virtual-device

I am new to cocos2d-x and I am unable to run cpp-tests on AVD but I can run them on Linux,(http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Linux) can I just go on with running codes on Linux but not AVD ? does it makes any difference ? I mean is it possible for me to just do everything and run the codes in Linux and finally I install my game on a real android device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent yes. But you will have to check your code every now and then on Android to make sure that everything is right.

Like any other cross platform solution, there are occasions that you will have to detect the device and then use some "device specific code". Having said that, the majority of your code will remain the same. For example in Cocos2d-x you will use this:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    // DO SOME IOS RELATED STUFF
#endif
```

PS: I have a question for you! Could you tell me what IDE you use on Linux? I wanted to use Eclipse and couldn't get the code completion feature working, so I gave up and moved to MAC. Let me know if you have a solution for a Linux IDE! Cheers!

Comment: I am using eclipse, but the virtual machine that comes with android SDK is very slow so I am using genymotion, but you should notice that you can not run cocos2d-x projects on genymotion by default! bedause genymotion do not add ARM and x86 artitecture automatically. check here to solve this problem (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Build_HelloWorld_on_android_x86_platform). and if you want to use cocos2d-x on windows check this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9ObAzm6rnQ&index=5&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is to block out code that should be platform specific by checking the built in `#defines`

Check `cocos2d/base/CCPlatFormConfig.h`

Then you can do:

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    // DO ANDROID SPECIFIC STUFF
#endif
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    // DO IOS SPECIFIC STUFF
#endif
```